# Issue is when run the test, driver running first test method and next test method is failing, also new browser is opening. any idea?

Tags: c#, selenium

written scripts using C# in Visual Studio 2013, Issue is when run the test, driver running first test method and next test method is failing, also new browser is opening. So when reaching next method driver connection is closed and starting new browser for each test method. any help pls? Below is the sample code i created :-

namespace AutomationProject
{
     [TestClass]
    public class ClassName
    {

```
public IWebDriver driver;
String baseUrl = "....";
//System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("restart.browser.each.scenario", "false",);
 [TestInitialize]
public void BeforeTest()
{
    /
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethoed1()
{

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl);
    .............
     .............

}
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethoed2()
{
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='submitInput']")).Click();
```

.........................
     ..........................

```
}

 [TearDown]
public void CloseDriver()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    driver.Close();
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after spending longtime,
**issue is** 
first method is executed successfully. While reaching next test method current web driver is closing and new driver is opening so am getting new browser.

Solution is :

I used Nuint frame work and used [TestfixtureSetup] -> driver will start before stating test mathods , [TestFixtureTearDown] -> this will close the driver once all test method executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, when second method is being run on new browser window, which is empty is empty, so your call to find input field fails. Use drover.Navigate().GoToUrl() to get to a page you have the submit element